# Building a stand alone C++ exe. Linking statically with msbuild

Tags: c++, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I currently have a C++ project that is built using msbuild.
Once the project is built I get an exe along with multiple dll files.
Is there a way to tell msbuild to link to those libraries statically ?
I cannot open the project in visual studio but I can make changes to the vcxproj.
Any suggestions on how I can accomplish that ?

Comment: Change the project types to static library, instead of dynamic library. It's not part of msbuild, it's part of the project properties.

Answer (score 1):

In the vcxproj files, change:

```xml
<ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
```

To

```xml
<ConfigurationType>StaticLibrary</ConfigurationType>
```

Also, in the `PreprocessorDefinitions` section(s), remove `xxx_EXPORTS` (where xxx is the name of the project) and `_USRDLL`, and replace with `_LIB`

Note: each of these (including `ConfigurationType`) will appear once for each Configuration you have (i.e. Debug, Release, etc.).

Comment: Thanks. The configuration type I have says ConfigurationType  `<ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>` . It has <AdditionalDependencies> on other lib files and I need to copy the dll of those files along with my exe

Comment: @Rajeshwar, I'm a bit confused. Do you have access to the vcxproj files of the DLL projects, or just to the executable's?

Comment: I only have access to the lib and dll files. Unfortunately I do not have access to the vcxproj of the dll projects.

Comment: @Rajeshwar, sorry, I misunderstood the what you meant when you said you have the vcxproj. In that case, then no, what you are asking is not possible. You would need the original projects in order to change their types.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add a lib file into a clean project, and the modification of vcxproj file are below, hope it can help you:

1. **Library Paths** and **Include Directories**
   [image]
2. **Additional Dependencies**
   [image]